# Programmatically encrypting a config-file in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, encryption, configuration-files

Could somebody please do a rundown of how to programmatically encrypt a config-file in .NET, preferably in C#.

What I would like to do is do some kind of check on an application's startup to see if a section is unprotected, and if it is, then encrypt it. This for both settings and connection-strings.

Also if anyone could list the types of encryption-providers and what is the difference between them.

I don't know if the code for doing this in a normal WinForms-application is transparent to doing this in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To summarize the answers and what I've found so far, here are some good links to answer this question:

- [Encrypting Configuration Information in ASP.NET 2.0 Applications - 4GuysFromRolla.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx)
- [How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections in ASP.NET 2.0 Using DPAPI - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998280.aspx)

Please feel free to complement with other links, maybe some to WinForms- or WPF-applications.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good article from 4 guys about [Encrypting Configuration Information in ASP.NET 2.0 Applications](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043331/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

The solution at below site working fine for me.

http://www.a2zmenu.com/Blogs/CSharp/How-to-encrypt-configuration-file.aspx

Answer (score 1):

@TK: a hashing algo can only be 'guessed', not reverse engineered. One can only reconstruct the input to a hash value by completely guessing the input (apart from collisions, that is) This can be done by a rainbow crack for example (see [an implementation of a rainbow cracker here](http://www.antsight.com/zsl/rainbowcrack/))

I would say that a 3rd party encryption tool is not safer than the .NET framework encryption algorithms, these libraries just help you doing your job faster

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but the Microsoft Enterprise library has good encryption support that will possibly suit your needs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc309503.aspx