# How can remove connectionstring from webconfig?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a project that has 3 layers.

1)Interface (It is an MVC project with View and Controller)

2)BI (It is a class library project)

3)DAL (It Is A class library that work with Entity Framework DataBase First)

My Problem :

There is a connection string in webconfig of the first project(MVC). But I want remove it. then the other layers should use of DAL Connection Strings.

But when I delete the connection string from that it cant connect and work with DB !!

I remember when I was working with ASP.NET and Linq to sql it was posible.

Please help me.

Comment: Once deployed, the only configuration that will be available will be the web.config of your MVC project. If you want to remove it you could hard code the connection string but I wouldn't recommend that

Comment: but it seems Irrational!!! Interface doesn't work with database directly!!. So, Why it needs connection string?!!! in other hand this method hasn't good security for saving connection string.every one can see user name and passwords am I right ?

Comment: You can encrypt your connection strings inside of your web.config. IIS will not service web.config file, so a user will not have access to your connection string that easily.

Comment: Thank u for reply. I read about encrypting connection string. But i think I can't use in web hosting(farms). Because of RSA keys. Am i right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once deployed, the only configuration that will be available will be the web.config of your MVC project. Instead of removing the connection string you could just encrypt it.

- [ASP.NET Connection String Encryption / Protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760745/asp-net-connection-string-encryption-protection)
- [Programmatically encrypting a config-file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965/programmatically-encrypting-a-config-file-in-net)
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b.aspx

Personally I'm using a mechanism based on that blog post. I have an administrative api call on my web application to send the information that must be encrypted.
 - http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/09/28/encrypt-and-decrypt-connectionstring-section-in-web-config.aspx