# Encrypt segments of config file (Settings.settings)

Tags: c#, encryption, passwords, settings

I have a password which I save on the Settings.settings file
and I want the section to be encrypted.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.protectsection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) is a tip I got, but I don't really know how to apply it.

Can anybody give me an Idea, as to how I could encrypt such a password?

[image: Settings]

Comment: http://www.rahulchugh.com/2011/09/digitally-signing-appconfig.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to encrypt the section, only the value for the password.

An example of how to encrypt/decrypt a password is shown here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/304187/how-to-create-password-encrypt-decrypt-in-csharp

I hope this helps.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

Search a bit, you can find quite a lot of information on this topic here on SO.

Here is a thread that has some interesting links in it:

[Programmatically encrypting a config-file in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965/programmatically-encrypting-a-config-file-in-net?rq=1)